# Equivalence between the two definitions of the Lebesgue Integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Royden defines the Lebesgue integral as :

> $$\int_E f = \sup \{\int_E\phi_n:\phi_n \text{ simple}, \phi_n \le f\} \cdots (A)$$

On a later occasion, he defines the Lebesgue Integral as :

> $\int_E f = \sup \{\int_Eh:h \text{ is bounded, measurable, of finite support, and } 0 \le h \le f, \phi_n \le f\}$

> $\cdots (B)$

Also,  the support set $E_0$ for a a measurable function $f$ on a set $E$ is defined as $E_0=\{x \in E | f(x) \ne 0\}$ and $m(E_0)$ is finite. The function f is then identically $0$ on $E−E_0$.

I am trying to prove the equivalence between the two definitions.

Using the Simple Approximation Lemma, we know that $f$ is any extended real valued measurable function $\iff$ it is possible to define a sequence of simple functions $\{\phi_n\}, ~\phi_n \le f$ that converge to $f$

However, using this definition, how does one introduce the set of finite support as required in definition $(B)$? The simple function in step $(A)$ might not even assume the value $0$ anywhere. So, how do we talk about the complement of the support set. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to assume $f\ge 0$. Moreover, if one of the $\sup$ is infinite, then so is the other. Thus let us assume w.o.l.g. that they are finite both. Then any simple function $\phi\le f$ clearly has finite support and is bounded. Thus the simple functions in $(A)$ are a subset of the functions $h$ in $(B)$. Now by your simple approximation lemma, any bounded, measurable $h$ may be approximated arbitrarily precisely by simple functions from below. This gives you the equivalence.

Comment: A simple function may not assume the value $0$ anywhere. Hence, outside a set $E_0$ of finite measure, it may not be able to assume the value $0$ anywhere. Thus, how are we able to talk about the support set?

Comment: What do you mean by this? the zero function is a simple function, isn't it?

Comment: Royden defines the support set $E_0$ for a a measurable function $f$ on a set $E$ as $E_0 = \{x \in E~|~f(x) \ne 0\}$ and $m(E_0)$ is finite. The function $f$ is then identically $0$ on $E - E_0$

Comment: What is assumed for $f$?

Comment: Edited above for the full definition

Comment: You also assume $m(E)$ finite?

Comment: Nope. $m(E) $ may be infinite. But $m(E_0)$ has to be finite

Comment: Thus for many natural $f$ (e.g. $f=exp(-x^2)$) one cannot define $E_0$?

Comment: As per the definition, it does seem so ...